# Minimum of a set in Coq

Tags: set, coq

I have a set `Ensemble R`, that regroups elements in R that satisfy some properties. What I would like is to find the smallest element in my set.

I thought I could use `Lub.Rbar_Glb` but this complicate a lot further proofs.

Is there a better way to do so?

Update:

I think a better way would be to look for the infimum of my set instead of the minimum. How could I complete this ?

Comment: Can you confirm you are referring to [library `Coq.Sets.Ensembles`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html)? (Unfortunate naming, “ensemble” is the French term, in English it is called a “set”, hence my question.)

Comment: You're going to need some extra constraints. Assuming that R means the real numbers, not every set contains its lower bound. For example, the set of positive numbers has no minimum.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed referring to https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sets.Ensembles.html.

Comment: Does your set have a lower bound, i.e. is it closed from below?  For example, the set `Gt1 x := x > 1.` does not have a smallest element.

Comment: (I meant, "does your set contain its lower bound")

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It is indeed something I did wrong